# Why does my function only work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, internet-explorer

Basically I have inherited this code where graphs are displayed/hidden, counters increased etc. I've debugged it to perfection in Firefox but in IE and Chrome I'm receiving an error along with weird behavior.

When console.logged, the parameters appear different and incorrect in IE/Chrome but are just fine in Firefox as shown below:

Can anyone tell me why functions/parameters are not being recognised in IE/Chrome?

My code below uses `substr` and the error I'm getting is:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substr' of undefined**

In Chrome/IE only because obviously it's not showing the full length and is only 3 letters long, when it's supposed to be 15+ as shown in the Firefox console log.

**Updated function with logs**

```
  function loadGraphs(idTreeview,idSelectGraph)
{

    console.log("loadGraphs function");
    var count=0;

    var fn=$('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].attributes[1].value;

    console.log("fn  = " + fn);

    fn=fn.substr(12).substr(0,fn.length-2);

    var flags=fn.split(new RegExp(","));
    console.log("value of flags = " + flags);
    var data=''; 
    console.log("value of fn = " + fn);

    console.log("value of # + idSelectGraph = " + $('#'+idSelectGraph));

    var idInstanceTreeview = idTreeview;

if($('#counterTreeviewUL'+idInstanceTreeview).length == 0) 
    {

    console.log('If length is 0 then do nothing');

      var fnInstance=$('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].attributes[1].value;

      console.log('If length is 0 then do nothing 2');


    var flagsInstance=fnInstance.split(new RegExp(","));

    console.log('If length is 0 then do nothing 3');    

    console.log("fn = " + fn);
    console.log("flags = " + flags);
    console.log("flagsInstance = " + flagsInstance);

    var graph = {
            id: seqId,
            entityName: flags[6].substr(1).substr(0, flags[6].length - 2),
            entity: flags[5].substr(1).substr(0, flags[5].length - 2),
            idCounter: flags[4],
            counterName: flags[3].substr(1).substr(0, flags[3].length - 2),
            ivmanager: flags[7].substr(1).substr(0, flags[7].length - 2),
            chart: null,
            pointsToShowX: null,
            borneInf: null,
            unite: "",
            idInstance: flagsInstance[2].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[2].length - 2),
            instanceName: flagsInstance[3].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[3].length - 2),
            listPdsNull: new Array(),
            countInstance: idTreeview + "_" + i,
            countGraph: -1
        };


    console.log('If length is 0 then do nothing 4');

    seqId++;
    graphs[graphsLastId]=graph;
    graphsLastId++;

    }

else 
  {
    console.log('Else if length is not 0');
    for(var i=0;i<$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idInstanceTreeview)[0].children.length;i++)
        ($('#counterTreeviewUL'+idInstanceTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].checked)?++count:count;

    if ($('#counterTreeviewUL'+idInstanceTreeview)[0].children.length == count)
    {
        console.log('If length is equal to count');
        $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].checked=true;
        $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].indeterminate=false;
    }
    else if (count==0)
    {
        console.log('Else if length is equal to 0');
        $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].checked=true;       
        $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].indeterminate=false;        
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Else if none of them conditions are true');
        $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].checked=true;
        $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].indeterminate=false;
    }


   for (var i=0;i<$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children.length;i++)
   {

        if (!$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].checked)
        {   
            $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].checked=true;

            var fnInstance=$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].attributes[1].value;
            console.log('fnInstance (1) = ' + fnInstance);

            fnInstance=fnInstance.substr(15).substr(0,fnInstance.length-2);
            console.log('fnInstance (2) = ' + fnInstance);

            var flagsInstance=fnInstance.split(new RegExp(","));
            console.log('flagsInstance = ' + flagsInstance);


              console.log("fn = " + fn);
              console.log("flags = " + flags);
              console.log("flagsInstance = " + flagsInstance);

            console.log('This is the substr error in Chrome');


            var graph = {
                    id: seqId,
                    entityName: flags[6].substr(1).substr(0, flags[6].length - 2),
                    entity: flags[5].substr(1).substr(0, flags[5].length - 2),
                    idCounter: flags[4],
                    counterName: flags[3].substr(1).substr(0, flags[3].length - 2),
                    ivmanager: flags[7].substr(1).substr(0, flags[7].length - 2),
                    chart: null,
                    pointsToShowX: null,
                    borneInf: null,
                    unite: "",
                    idInstance: flagsInstance[2].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[2].length - 2),
                    instanceName: flagsInstance[3].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[3].length - 2),
                    listPdsNull: new Array(),
                    countInstance: idTreeview + "_" + i,
                    countGraph: -1
                };


            console.log('Does it fail after var graph?');

            seqId++;        
            graphs[graphsLastId]=graph;     
            graphsLastId++;
        }
    }

 }
    graphsToLoad=false;
    console.log("before updateAllGraphs");
    updateAllGraphs();
    console.log("after updateAllGraphs");
    loading=false;

    if($('#counterTreeviewUL'+idInstanceTreeview).length == 0)
    {

      if($('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].checked)
          {
             console.log("If it is checked then execute countSelectedGraphs(1)");
           countSelectedGraphs(graphsLastId, flags[5].substr(1).substr(0,flags[5].length-2), 0);
          }
      else 
          {
             console.log("If it is not checked then execute countSelectedGraphs(0)");
           countSelectedGraphs(graphsLastId, flags[5].substr(1).substr(0,flags[5].length-2), 0);
          }
    }

    else 
    {
            console.log("If it is not equal to 0 then execute countSelectedGraphs(0)");
          countSelectedGraphs(graphsLastId, flags[5].substr(1).substr(0,flags[5].length-2), 0);

    }
}
```

---

The **first console log** (line 2) is the result of `($('#'+idSelectGraph)[0]);`

The **second console log** (line 3) is the result of `($('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].attributes[1]);`

The **third console log** is the result of `($('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].attributes[1].value);` etc.

---

**Full console.log returned in chrome/IE:**

[image]

**Full console.log returned in Firefox (works correctly):**

[image]

### EDIT 1

I've now fixed everything above, my only problem is a line I've replaced causes the graphs shown to be all the same as the first one found, as opposed to each individual graph before. This code is good as it means my application works in IE and Chrome, but this error has to be resolved and will be rewarded:

Original code (all graphs were shown correctly, but didn't work in IE/Chrome)

```
var fnInstance=$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].attributes[1].value;
```

New code (works in Chrome/IE, but only shows the first graph found)

```
$el = $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first();
            var fnInstance = $el.find("input").attr("onclick");
```

Can anyone tell me how I can tweak the new code to get all graphs successfully (possibly has something to do with the `i` variable).

### EDIT 2

My for-loop is the following now after editing:

```
   for (var i=0;i<$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children.length;i++)
   {

        if (!$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].checked)
        {   
            $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].checked=true;


    This works in Firefox but not in Chrome/IE  //  var fnInstance=$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].attributes[1].value;

            This works in all but only displays first graph //

            $el = $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first();
            var fnInstance = $el.find("input").attr("onclick");

            fnInstance=fnInstance.substr(15).substr(0,fnInstance.length-2);


            var flagsInstance=fnInstance.split(new RegExp(","));


            var graph = {
                    id: seqId,
                    entityName: flags[6].substr(1).substr(0, flags[6].length - 2),
                    entity: flags[5].substr(1).substr(0, flags[5].length - 2),
                    idCounter: flags[4],
                    counterName: flags[3].substr(1).substr(0, flags[3].length - 2),
                    ivmanager: flags[7].substr(1).substr(0, flags[7].length - 2),
                    chart: null,
                    pointsToShowX: null,
                    borneInf: null,
                    unite: "",
                    idInstance: flagsInstance[2].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[2].length - 2),
                    instanceName: flagsInstance[3].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[3].length - 2),
                    listPdsNull: new Array(),
                    countInstance: idTreeview + "_" + i,
                    countGraph: -1
                };


        }
```

Comment: `var fnInstance=$('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].attributes[1].value;` would need the related HTML to know how this is supposed to work but accessing attributes by index is probably the issue as browsers would likely not ensure consistent ordering and it looks like you're getting a different attribute.  I'd suggest replacing that by operating on the jQuery wrapper and explicitly specifying the attribute: `fnInstance=$('#'+idSelectGraph).first().attr(attrName);`

Comment: What is `attributes[1]` of your element? Attribute order is not defined.

Comment: No, it is not a parameter of your `loadGraphs` function, it is a property of a DOM node (which is supposed to be selected by ID). But what do you expect its value to be? And on which line do you get your exception?

Comment: @Bergi The error occurs where the second var graph is created as in Chrome/IE, flags is cut down to 3 digits long, so there is no such thing as flags[6] so the graphs aren't selected and checkboxes aren't checked (but Firefox as you can see the parameters in console.logs display and that's why it works)

Comment: Isn't `flags` supposed to be an array? I can't see that from your output - you might show us your debug code with the `console.log` statements.

Comment: @Bergi Sure thing - I've updated the code to show the console logs, and below what they return when I try to run it in IE/Chrome. Also I've put below it the full log I return in Firefox

Comment: @Bergi I've updated the pictures - if you look at the 'onclick="..."' bit on the firefox, that's what the console log of $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].attributes[1] is.. however you can see in Chrome/IE it only returns id=... and this is the problem

Comment: @MattWhipple I've updated the question with the values of what you asked + better console logs

Comment: Did you make any success with your issue? Did you consider my last comment?

Comment: @Christoph I've just got to work now so I'll try it out and let you know, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

1) replace every piece of code which operates on the attribute of a dom-Element via array-notation e.g. by using the jQuery wrapper `attr()` where you can access the attribute by name or via `attributes.onclick /*or*/ attributes["onclick"]`.

Reason: The order of the attributes is not defined, you might access a wrong attribute when using the array notation. (Which you actually do when looking at the console output: IE/Chrome fetch the `id` attribute while FF fetches the `onclick` attribute) Old IEs also list several additional attributes for the DOM-Elements (attached handlers, internal attributes), making this method of access completely worthless.

This should most likely fix your issue...

Additionally:

2) cache your jQuery Elements:

```
var $graph = $('#'+idSelectGraph);
```

and use `$graph` instead for each subsequent calls. This will improve performance and makes refactoring much more easy.

3) use `split(",")` (String) instead of `split(new RegExp(","))` (Regex) for better performance.

EDIT in response to your comment:

```
var fnInstance= $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0]
                              .children[i].children[0].attribu‌tes[1].value;
```

should be something like this:

```
$el = $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first();
var fnInstance = $el.find("id/class/name of the node").attr("name");
```

EDIT2:

If i understood your code correctly,

```
for (var i=0;i<$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children.length;i++)
   {

        if (!$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].checked)
        {   
            $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].checked=true;
            $el = $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first();
            var fnInstance = $el.find("input").attr("onclick");
```

should look like this

```
$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first().children().each(function(){

       $el = $(this).children().first();

       if (!$el.prop("checked")){
          $el.prop("checked",true);
          var fnInstance = $el.attr("onclick");
```

Comment: Agreed, I'm going through now and changing it because it's not accessible by index. Can you tell me what I change var fnInstance=$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].attributes[1].value; too as I can't seem to get this line changed properly.

Comment: As in I don't know how to make it access the wrapper instead, I've tried var fnInstance=$('#'+idSelectGraph).first().children([i]).children([0]).attr('onclick'); but it comes back as undefined

Comment: the mixture of jquery and native javascript is problematic. At first, use the opportunity and cache the jQuery element, then it might be clever to use the jquery `find()` method instead if `children.children`  and finally you need to figure out, which attribute you exactly want to select with `attributes[1]` - do a console.log in firefox to find out the name. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Hello, the edit works brilliantly in that it works in Chrome and IE - however if I 'select all' graphs in one go, it just shows however many versions of the first graph found (as opposed to all the different graphs the former line showed in firefox) any recommendations or improvements available on your edit? I'll offer a bounty.

Comment: It's something that the original 

var fnInstance did that the $el = $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first();
   var fnInstance = $el.find("input").attr("onclick"); does not. I think it might be to do with the 'i' variable that was used in the one before but not in your edit.

Comment: @user1394965 I'm not exactly sure how your code looks like now, but you have to iterate through all elements of `$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)`. In my code i just made the assumption you'd take the first element: `$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first();` (which is the case for your if-branch) so in the else-branch (more than one elements), you need to operation on all elements - you can take [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for that. See if you can make it work with that hints.

Comment: I've edited to show you what I've got in my for-loop. Can I simply replace first with each or will this not do anything? Sorry I'm insanely new to Javascript/JQuery and this code has just been dumped on me :/

Comment: I simply cannot work out the statement I need for each, I tried $le = $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).each();
   var fnInstance = $le.find("input").attr("onclick"); but this doesn't work either

Comment: Ok thanks! I think it's something to do with the selectors.. I've tried using children() closest() and contents() but to no avail so far.. I just can't work out the difference between it and the original statement which works (in firefox)

Comment: Sorry to ask but when do you finish work? 5pm German time? As I can only test when I'm here and I finish at 7pm Luxembourg time (I think this is 6pm German time?)

Comment: You need to iterate over `$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first().children()`.

Comment: Ok yeah got that part, it was mainly confusion over how I can do if the if statement and what is the alternative to $el = $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first();
    var fnInstance = $el.find("input").attr("onclick");

Comment: Replacing the code with what you put doesn't seem to compile sadly :/

Comment: Is there no way of simply changing to two $el lines to do what I said or does the for/if statements have to be changed in order for this to work:

Comment: Well, if really nothing else is helping and you dont get it to work, replace `var fnInstance=$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].attributes[1].value;` with that line: `var fnInstance=$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].attributes.onclick.value;` and leave the rest as it is.